# python 3.4.3 64bit a program required for this install could not be run

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, 64-bit

Trying to install Python 3.4.3 64-Bit and it gives me the following error:
'There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support or package vendor'
I have no bloody idea what this means so please help. Thanks in advance
I'm the admin on my computer and have all permissions
My windows is 64bit and is Windows 8.1

Comment: btw: One thing I thought may help you help me is that on the installer it thinks I already have a Python34 file (I don't, but I used to) I have tried re-downloading the Python installer

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? Is it 64-bit? Where did you get the Python installer? Do you have administrative privileges on your computer? Have you had issues installing other programs recently? Was a `C:\Python34` folder created on your computer, and does it have any files/folders in it? Please [edit] your question and include as much data about the situation as possible, because as it currently stands we don't have the slightest idea what might be happening.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same phenomenon occur when trying to clean up (uninstall various versions of Python and perform a clean install of 3.4.3) on my Windows 7 64-bit laptop.  Unfortunately, I cannot tell you *what* "program required for this install to complete could not be run". Repeated attempts to "install for all users" produced the same "could not be run" (followed by a roll back of the install).  Just before getting out Orca and diving into the innards of the MSI file, I attempted an "install just for me", and the install completed. I am, in fact, the only (human) user of this computer.  There is another user account that was created during a cygwin setup, and access to some aspect of that user's profile/resources may have been the issue. If you are installing Python for your own use - and not as a "platform-wide" resource for other users as well - you might try installing "just for me".

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was that I had an older version of Python installed, that the MSI could not un-install.  I had to manually remove it first.
This is how I resolved the problem on my Windows7 machine...

1. Open a command prompt and navigate to the location of the python.exe. (For me this was C:\Python34.)
2. Execute this command

   ```
   python3 -B -m ensurepip._uninstall
   ```
3. Close the command prompt.
4. Using the python MSI file for the version of Python I had previously installed (yes, I went to the Python archive and downloaded the MSI for the old version), install Python again, but without the "pip" package. (Not sure if this is necessary, but it worked for me.)
5. Using the same Python MSI file, uninstall Python completely.
6. Using another MSI, for the version of Python you wish to install, you should now be able to perform a "clean" install.

Comment: This worked for me too. I downloaded the old installation (3.4.2), repaired it with the installer, then changed it with the installer and removed pip, and then I installed the new version (3.4.3).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while uninstalling the python file from the control panel. It prompts

```
There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support or package vendor
```

I have solved this problem by installing the specific *python-<version>.amd64.msi*.

I then executed the MSI file. It asks for Change, repair, remove. First, click on Change radio button and complete execution. Later you can come to control panel and repair or uninstall the python file.

Comment: In my case Change didn't work, but Repair, then Remove did.

Answer (score 0):

Poking around, there is a temp file saying:

> Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A
>   program required for this install to complete could not be run.
>   Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: UpdatePip,
>   location: C:\Programs\PY272\python.exe, command: -m ensurepip -U
>   --default-pip 
>   === Logging stopped: 6/12/2015  13:26:17 ===

OK, so the missing "Voldemort" file (that which shall not be mentioned) is the ensurepip package.  There is documentation for ensurepip at https://docs.python.org/2/library/ensurepip.html. I am still on 2.7, but it looks like this is a shared problem with Py 3.

The documentation says the ensurepip package is new in 2.7.9. My solution: install a version prior to 2.7.9 and then upgrade the files myself from an existing install. Done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms as OP. In my case, i had two separate installs, one of 2.7 and one of 3.4.3 and when i checked the PATH variable, there were 2 lines about PYTHONPATH pointing to the 2.7 version.

I removed the lines and then the repair funciton of the MSI did work. I uninstalled both versions and proceeded to reinstall.

Done :)

On a Win7 box: 
`Startup/ right click on Computer / Properties / Advanced system settings / Environment variables` then check both sub-windows for paths related to python.

Answer (score 0):

I had just the exact problem. But in mine case i've additionally removed the `c:\python27` and `c:\python36` directories and associated installers got stuck around Install/Uninstall and could not completely repair the installation (the `/Scripts` subdirectory has been missed and the python.exe reported an error about missed `encodings` module).

But i've found a solution for myself. Seems somehow the `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` environment variables (and may be `PATH` too) has been interfering with the Python installation process. But because i could not run Uninstall from the Windows Uninstall list in the Control Panel, then i did this:

1. Cleanup the `PATH` environment variable from all python path occurrences.
2. Remove `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` environment variables.
3. Restart Windows Explorer if environment variables (console command `set PY` must return the empty list) is not updated.
4. Run repair from (!) the python-3.4.4*.exe/python-2.7.11*.exe executables (download it if not done yet). Icons in the Windows Uninstall list in the Control Panel will reset into the original state for a repaired python installation.
5. Run the Uninstall from the same executables or from Windows Uninstall list in the Control Panel.

And it did the trick!

If you still needs the both versions of the python installation, then try install the older versions before the new versions. Seems it's important too.